# How to use templates in a c++ linked list?

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I don't fully understand the concept of templates and am trying to get some help on how to implement one on my linked list below. I'm trying to get my code to be able to support the following types : `List< List<std::string> >` `List<std::string>` `List<int>`. I was wondering if there was any way someone could give me an example of how to convert these items into templates in addition to trying to explain what is happening? I'm new to c++ so any help I can get would be appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>


using Item = std::string;

// TURN DList into a template!
class DList {
private:

  class DListNode {
  public:
    Item item;
    DListNode * next;
    DListNode * prev;
    DListNode(Item i, DListNode *n=nullptr, DListNode *p=nullptr) {
      item = i;      
      next = n;
      prev = p;
    }
  };

  DListNode * head;
  DListNode * tail;

public:
  class iterator {
    DListNode *node;
  public:
    iterator(DListNode *n = nullptr) {
      node = n;
    }

    Item& getItem() { return node->item; }
    void next() { node = node->next; }
    void prev() { node = node->prev; }
    bool end() { return node==nullptr; }

    friend class DList;
  };



public:
  DList() {
    // list is empty
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
  }

  bool empty() {
    return head==nullptr;
  }

  void append(Item a) {
    DListNode *node = new DListNode(a,nullptr,tail);
    if ( head == nullptr ) {
      // empty list
      head = node;
      tail = node;
    } else {
      tail->next = node;
      tail = node;
    }
  }

  void insertAfter(iterator it, Item item)
  {
    if(head == nullptr || it.node == nullptr) { // NULL iterator means insert at head
      DListNode *node = new DListNode(item,head); // next=head, prev=NULL
      if ( head == nullptr) // same as zyBook
        head = tail = node;
      else { // if inserting before head, it.node==NULL
        head->prev = node;
        head = node;
      }
    } else if (it.node == tail) {
      DListNode *node = new DListNode(item,nullptr,tail); // next=NULL, prev=old tail
      tail->next = node;
      tail = node;
    } else {
      DListNode *node = new DListNode(item,it.node->next,it.node);
      it.node->next = node;
      node->next->prev = node;
    }
  }

  void erase (iterator it) {
    DListNode *succ = it.node->next; // successor node
    DListNode *pred = it.node->prev; // predecessor node

    if (succ != NULL)
      succ->prev = pred;
    if (pred != NULL)
      pred->next = succ;

    if (it.node == head)
      head = succ; // head is following node
    if (it.node == tail)
      tail = pred; // tail is previous node

    delete it.node; // delete the node; not shown in zyBook, but necessary in C/C++
    // iterator is now invalid, caller should not use it again
  }

  iterator begin() {
    return iterator(head);
  }

  iterator reverse_begin() {
    return iterator(tail);
  }
};

template <typename Item>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, DList<Item> &l)
{
  out << "{";
  auto it = l.begin();
  out << it.getItem();
  it.next();
  for(; !it.end(); it.next())
    {
      out << ", " << it.getItem();
    }
  out << "}" << std::endl;
  return out;
}


int main()
{
  {
    DList<std::string> l;

    l.append("eggs");
    l.append("milk");
    l.append("bread");

    std::cout << l;
  }
  {
    DList<int> l;

    l.append(1);
    l.append(2);
    l.append(3);

    std::cout << l;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: templates are an advanced topic. If you are new to them and c++ in general you probably better start with something way simpler. You wouldnt gain much if you would get your code turned into template code as answer when it does not come with >10 pages of explanation. Maybe you can turn your question into asking one specific more focused question?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you almost have all you need, but you are still using a regualar class with a concrete type.

```
using Item = std::string;

class DList { ... };
```

So first we drop the concrete type:

```
// using Item = std::string;

class DList { ... }; // sure Item is now undefined...
```

Then we tell the class to be a template

```
template <typename Item>
class DList { ... };
```

Now `Item` got re-introduced, but instead of being a concrete type, it's now a generic one. That's it, you have a template list (assuming the list is implemented correctly, I didn't check).

Whenever you now instantiate your list:

```
DList<int>;
DList<std::string>;
// ...
```

You create a totally new, independent data type (which means especially, that you cannot assign a `DList<int>` to a pointer to `DList<double>`, just all alike as you cannot assign a int to a pointer to double either).

When you instantiate a template, every occurence of a template parameter will be replaced with the type you instantiated the template with, e. g. in `DList<int>`, every occurence of `Item` will be replaced with `int`.

Well, all this is just a very short introduction, there's quite a lot to follow yet, but that's rather to be handled in book than in an answer on stackoverflow...

Some notes to your node's constructor, though:

```
DListNode(Item i /* , ... */) { item = i; }
```

At very first, you should get used to using constructor's initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`):

```
DListNode(Item i /* , ... */) : item(i) { }
```

You avoid default initiasation + assignment in favour of direct initialisation by value. Additionally, some types (non-default constructible ones, const members and references) *only* can be initialised that way.

Then you are producing an unnecessary copy:

```
DListNode(Item i /* , ... */) : item(i) { }
//             ^ temporary copy   ^ final copy, created from temporary
```

You avoid that copy, if you accept the item by reference:

```
DListNode(Item const& i /* , ... */) : item(i) { }
// now copies from reference, one copy less
```

You can additionally provide move semantics:

```
DListNode(Item&& i /* , ... */) : item(std::move(i)) { }
```

so that objects you don't need outside the list any more can be moved into (well, actually their contents). In some cases, this can be much cheaper than a full copy...

All said about the constructor (apart from the initialiser list) applies to the `append` and `insertAfter` functions as well.

Initialiser lists and avoiding copies is general advice, unrelated to templates...